# How to fix GCC error : "asm/socket.h: No such file" on Sli-Taz Linux?

Tags: c, sockets

Story : I tried compiling the code below on `Sli-Taz` Linux `32 bit`, as well as on `64 bit`. In both cases I get the same `gcc error`. I searched for `libc` packages in the `repo` and could not find anything named `libc-dev`. If I can not find a solution, I may also try it with `Alpine Linux`.

Compile error for : `gcc server.c`

```
In file included from /usr/include/sys/socket.h:40:0,
                 from server.c:5:
/usr/include/bits/socket.h:381:24: fatal error: asm/socket.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Code for : `server.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>

char response[] = "test";

int main()
{
  int one = 1, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
  socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    err(1, "can't open socket");

  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

  int port = 90;
  svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    err(1, "Can't bind");
  }

  listen(sock, 5);
  while (1) {
    client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);
    printf("Client IP : [%s]\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));

    if (client_fd == -1) {
      perror("Can't accept");
      continue;
    }

    write(client_fd, response, sizeof(response) - 1); /*-1:'\0'*/
    close(client_fd);
  }
```

Description of the `server.c` : It is a program that will listen to `port 90` and if a client tries to connect to `port 90`, it will respond to them with the message : `test`.

Comment: `asm/socket.h` is a header from the api exposed by linux kernel. What kernel are you running?

Comment: @Kamil Cuk,  The output for : `uname -srm` is : `Linux 3.16.55-slitaz i686`. So, I believe it is using Linux Kernel 3.16.

Comment: @Rup,  I searched the repo for "`headers`", Perhaps I should test this one ? `linux-api-headers 3.16.55 Kernel headers sanitized for use in userspace.`

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: @Rup, I installed it and the error is no longer present. Now there is a different error but it is not related to the same issue.  If you would like you can post it as an answer and I will select your answer as the `chosen answer`.

Comment: Comments are allowed to be edited within 5 minutes after they are posted. In the comment above I had not seen "`linux-api-headers`" . Perhaps the comment was edited and it was added after I posted a comment about having found an item named "`linux-api-headers`" in the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the [linux-api-headers](http://pkgs.slitaz.org/?filelist=linux-api-headers) package.

/usr/include/asm/* are APIs exposed by the kernel and so are generally taken from the kernel source and updated as you upgrade the installed kernel. In SliTaz this is the linux-api-headers package; in Red Hat-derived systems this is the kernel-headers package, or Ubuntu it's linux-headers or linux-headers-generic, etc.